# Remove row from array result from codeigniter query

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am executing below query in codeigniter which returns 4 rows:

```
$available_rooms = $this->db->query("SELECT id_room as id, ea_rooms.name as name FROM ea_rooms_services WHERE id_service =" . $service_id)->result_array();
```

Output e.g.:

```
 {
{id:1, name:a}
{id:2, name:b}
{id:3, name:c}
{id:4, name:d}
}
```

I have an array with room ids `$occupiedRooms` (e.g. `{0=>1, 1=>2}`) which is being populated as follows:

```
$occupiedRooms = array();

foreach ($listing as $element){
... SOMECODE
    if ($id_room != null)
         $occupiedRooms[] = $id_room;
}
```

I want to unset all rows in `$available_rooms` that have the same ids in `$occupiedRooms`.

Expected output:

```
 {
{id:3, name:c}
{id:4, name:d}
}
```

I am using below code but it is not working

```
foreach ($available_rooms as $elementKey => $element){
    if(in_array($element['id'], $occupiedRooms)){
       unset($available_rooms[$elementKey]);
    }
}
```

I also tried `array_filter` with below code but it also didn't work:

```
foreach ($occupiedRooms as $id){
    $available_rooms = array_filter($available_rooms, function($room) use($id)
        {
             return $room['id'] != $id;
        });
}
```

Comment: is your $occupiedRooms correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this would be shorter:

```
$occupied_rooms = array(1,5,6);

$available_rooms = $this->db->query("SELECT id_room as id, ea_rooms.name as name FROM ea_rooms_services WHERE id_service =" . $service_id . " AND id_room NOT IN ( " . implode(",", $occupied_rooms) . " ) ")->result_array();
```